# Obtaining public IP address rather than localhost (Boost Asio)

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, boost

I have the following connection set up, this works correctly. This is part of a larger piece of code which listens (at a free port), for incoming messages. What I am trying to do is publish the uri so that other clients can connect to this. However I cannot figure out a way for the endpoint.address() to appear as the actual IP address on the interface being used rather than "localhost". Any ideas?

```
 tcp::resolver::query query(address, "");
 tcp:: endpoint endpoint = *resolver.resolve(query);
 acc.open(endp.protocol());
 acc.set_option(reuse_address(true));
 acc.bind(endp);
 acc.listen();

 tcp::endpoint endpoint =  acc.local_endpoint() ; 
 string uri = "tcp://" + endpoint.address().to_string() + ":" + lexical_cast<string>(endpoint.port()) ;
```

Comment: Do you mean the LAN address of your PC or the public address of your router?

Comment: what is your WAN access configured like?

Comment: I cannot make assumptions on how WAN access is configured, this has to be very general. I need to find a way to infer the public address through which other hosts could send packets to this acceptor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost ASIO has no way to enum all the interfaces of your computer. resolver query your DNS for your IP, witch is not the same as it can return whatever you have configured in it (even inacurrate information can be retrieved).

If you want to bind to the default interface. you don't need to make a resolve.
Just create  the socket with the following endpoint :

```
 boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = 
      boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(),port);
```